# How to center an element regarding a background

Tags: html, css

I have an element `i` in the form of an icon to which I want to apply a style. The style is a circle-shaped background. I was able to apply the style that I wish, unfortunately the rendering is not the desired one. The background does not completely cover the element as you can see on the screenshot.

[image]

Here is the CSS code :

```
  #carousel-right{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

And the HTML one:

```
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: you need to add text-align: center to your #carousel-right and then just reduce the line height of your flaticon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform` like this

```css
body {
background: #ccc;
}

#carousel-right .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 26px;
}

#carousel-right{
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<a href="#" id="carousel-right" class="circle"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: its all mine pleasure. Happy coding mate

Answer (score 1):

Give `text-align:center` and `vertical-align:middle` to `i.fa-angle-left` class.

Answer (score 1):

use it as:

```
#carousel-right {
  position: relative;
}

#carousel-right > .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Comment: do you find it helpful?